# add a level in pygame

Tags: python, pygame

I wrote the level 1 of my game(you control the snake by up,down,right and left bottom key to eat the apple and the snake's length grows)but I don't know where to start the next level and how to write it
I mean I don't know if there's any class or thing for starting a new level in pygame;
[the explanation of level 2 just in case:there is two snakes that you control one of them like I said and computer(random) controls the other one and there are some walls as barriers;I want it to be like it goes to the next level when you hit the 5th score in level 1]
here's my code:

```
import pygame
import random
pygame.init()

#colors
black=(0,0,0)
crismon=(220,20,60)
white=(255,255,255)
vanila=(255,250,226)
pink=(255,204,255)

display_width=700
display_height=500

gameDisplay=pygame.display.set_mode((display_width,display_height))
#caption0
pygame.display.set_caption("Snake")

#icon
icon=pygame.image.load("the picture's path")
pygame.display.set_icon(icon)

clock=pygame.time.Clock()


block_size=10
#frames per second
fps=25

#font
font=pygame.font.SysFont(None,25)

#score
def score(score):
    text=font.render("Score:"+str(score),True,crismon)
    gameDisplay.blit(text,[0,0])

def message_to_screen(msg,color,y_displace=0):
    textSurf=font.render(msg,True,color)
    textRect=textSurf.get_rect()
    textRect.center=(display_width/2),(display_height/2)+y_displace
    gameDisplay.blit(textSurf,textRect)

def snake(block_size,snakeList):
    for XnY in snakeList:
        pygame.draw.rect(gameDisplay,crismon,[XnY[0],XnY[1],block_size,block_size])

def game_intro():
    intro=True
    while intro:
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type==pygame.QUIT:
                pygame.quit()
                quit()
            if event.type==pygame.KEYDOWN:
                if event.key==pygame.K_p:
                    intro=False
                if event.type==pygame.K_q:
                    pygame.quit()
                    quit()


        gameDisplay.fill(crismon)
        message_to_screen("Welcome to Snake",white,-70)
        message_to_screen("Eat the Apple!",white,-40)
        message_to_screen("Press P to play or Q to quit!",white,-10)
        pygame.display.update()

def gameLoop():
    gameExit=True

    lead_x=display_width/2
    lead_y=display_height/2

    lead_x_change=0
    lead_y_change=0

    snakeList=[]
    snakeLength=10

    randAppleX=round(random.randrange(0,display_width-block_size)/10.0)*10.0
    randAppleY=round(random.randrange(0,display_height-block_size)/10.0)*10.0

    while gameExit:
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type==pygame.QUIT:
                pygame.quit()
                quit()
            if event.type==pygame.KEYDOWN:
                if event.key==pygame.K_RIGHT:
                    lead_x_change=block_size
                    lead_y_change=0
                elif event.key==pygame.K_LEFT:
                    lead_x_change=-block_size
                    lead_y_change=0
                elif event.key==pygame.K_UP:
                    lead_y_change=-block_size
                    lead_x_change=0
                elif event.key==pygame.K_DOWN:
                    lead_y_change=block_size
                    lead_x_change=0
                elif event.key==pygame.K_q:
                    pygame.quit()
                    quit()

        if lead_x>=display_width or lead_x<0 or lead_y>=display_height or lead_y<0:
            pygame.quit()
            quit()

        lead_x+=lead_x_change
        lead_y+=lead_y_change

        gameDisplay.fill(pink)
        pygame.draw.rect(gameDisplay,black,[randAppleX,randAppleY,block_size,block_size])

        snakeHead=[]
        snakeHead.append(lead_x)
        snakeHead.append(lead_y)
        snakeList.append(snakeHead)

        if len(snakeList)>snakeLength:
            del snakeList[0]

        snake(block_size,snakeList)

        score(snakeLength-10)

        pygame.display.update()

        if lead_x==randAppleX and lead_y==randAppleY:
            pygame.mixer.music.load('the music's path')
            pygame.mixer.music.play(1)
            randAppleX=round(random.randrange(0,display_width-block_size)/10.0)*10.0
            randAppleY=round(random.randrange(0,display_height-block_size)/10.0)*10.0
            snakeLength+=1

        clock.tick(fps)

    pygame.quit()
    quit()

game_intro()
gameLoop()
```

Comment: i think you should define what a level entails before having them.  What makes the levels different?  How is it harder?  You can then define a LIST of levels and attributes/configurations which would be applied throughout the game.  You have an Idea it seems, but you need to define more criterion.

Comment: To elaborate on @Fallenreaper's comment: once you have defined what a level entails, you could encapsulate your level one in a class, or group of classes; do the same for level two, then changing levels is a matter of replacing level1 with level2

Comment: You need to make it more clear what you want to do. Do you want to reset everything and o on or keep it and go on. You need to be more specific.

Answer (score 1):

You question seems to be two fold.

First off, you want to have a different "level" which is completely different then the first level, lets say that your first level is the snake game you have above, but your second level to be a chess game.

In this case, a separate game loop would make the most sense. This is basically already what you are doing with the game intro.

```
game_intro() # First show that intro
gameSnakeLoop() # Then play the first level.
gameChessLoop() # Then play chess.
```

So you are practically coding two games and playing on after the other. Now, this may work but has a number of problems, first off all being this all really should be wrapped up into one main function.

```
def main():
    """Run the game."""
    game_intro() # First show that intro
    gameSnakeLoop() # Then play the first level.
    gameChessLoop() # Then play chess.

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Also, you would need to load constants for these two stages, which would make this longer.

**However**, it seems like you are more asking for a way to spawn an enemy eventually in the game. This is much more elegant. You would create a class or similar like `EnemySnake(pygame.sprite.Sprite)` and then would, at some determined "level 2" point, create an enemy snake. The class would be a sprite that contains some kind of thinking of how to move around and then is interacted with by the game loop.

If you are not famiar with sprites and sprite groups in pygame, I would recommend you do some reading here: https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/sprite.html.